# Power BI Dashboard "Too Many Values"

Tags: office365, business-intelligence, powerbi

I'm testing Power BI & I've developed a dashboard using "Power BI Desktop". I had no issues importing 5 million rows from SQL database.

I discovered an issue in *Map* and *Line Chart* visualizations 
I have an error message suggesting:

*Too Many Values. Not Showing All Date*.
[image]

What can I do about this error message? What is the limit of rows that can be displayed in a visualization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of columns(+ measures + calculated fields) you can import into Power BI: 2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647 (SQL Server 2016) in the datamodel.
You can easily load the 5mill+ rows into the datamodel. But the Power BI Team currently states that the columns/axis fields can handle about 2000 fields in reports and dashboards. The maximum amount of rows for calculations is more, but it depends on the visual u use.
So if you want to use a large dataset they advise you to categorise it.
They state that they're currently working on improving this.